# Fill grid with the users input

Tags: c++

Okay, so I am a bit stuck. I am trying to ask the user to enter 16 characters and output their input into a grid. However, I keep running into an error:

> Error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char' in assignment.

I don't understand what the error is and I did my best to try and figure out the issue but not working.

For example:

1. User enters 1234123412341234
2. It should output:

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void fillLgArray(char grid[][LG_GRID], int direction);

void outputLgArray(char grid[][LG_GRID]);


int main(){

    char myGrid1[LG_GRID][LG_GRID];
    doCommand (myGrid1);

  return 0;
}


void fillLgArray(char grid[][LG_GRID], int direction){

  string userInput;

  cout << "Please enter 16 characters!\n";
  cin >> userInput;

  if(userInput.length() > 16){

      userInput = userInput.substr(0, 16);
  }

  cout << "You entered " << userInput << endl;

  if (direction = 1){
      for (int row = 0; row < LG_GRID; row++){
          for (int col = 0; row < LG_GRID; row++){
                grid [row][col] = userInput;
        }
    }
  }
}

void outputLgArray(char grid[][LG_GRID]){

    for (int row=0;row <LG_GRID;row++){
    for(int col=0;col <LG_GRID;col++){
      cout << grid[row][col]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grid [row][col] = userInput;
```

You are trying to assign the whole `userInput` (which has type `std::string` aka `std::__cxx11::basic_string` and is multiple characters long) to a single character `grid[row][col]` (which is of type `char`). Specify *which* character of the string you want to save in the `grid[row][col]`:

```
grid [row][col] = userInput[...];
```

Replace `...` by the character index you want to choose.

Not related to question:

```
for (int col = 0; row < LG_GRID; row++){
```

`row` should be `col` in both cases, otherwise you are not ever actually changing `col`.